# D7 sites/default/files/.htaccess caused unloaded css&pictures&etc...

Tags: theming, files, .htaccess

After an error [SA-CORE-2013-003 - Drupal core - Multiple vulnerabilities] 
notice showed up in my site's status report page, 
I rewrote the content according to this 
https://www.drupal.org/SA-CORE-2013-003, and the error itself was solved and gone.

but it turned out that all css and pictures of my site were entirely lost!!
it may mean that all the thing from sites/default/files are not loaded now.

What I did was that just changing the content of .htaccess at sites/default/files.
now, I tried to change the content of .htaccess back to former one, 
but the gone css and pictures still can't be applied again...

Im using Drupal 7.34, I don't know how to fix it.
please someone could help me?

Comment: What is the .htaccess file contents? I wonder if you have a typo.

Comment: Hi, like below.

The former content:
SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006
Options None
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

Comment: And suggested content I wrote:
# Turn off all options we don't need.
Options None
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Set the catch-all handler to prevent scripts from being executed.
SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006
<Files *>
  # Override the handler again if we're run later in the evaluation list.
  SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2013_003
</Files>

# If we know how to do it safely, disable the PHP engine entirely.
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_flag engine off
</IfModule>

Comment: Do you have a site URL? I'm thinking you removed something from the .htaccess that is causing issues for you.
I'm assuming you don't have a backup of the .htaccess file.

Comment: Hi nmillin, sorry site URL can't be known until site's construction finishes. yes I may have removed something but I do have a backup of original .htaccess file with the content as below:

Comment: The former content: SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006 Options None Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

Comment: not sure but I have changed permissions of around sites,default,files folders and the .htaccess and setting.php, because of disallowed rewriting to the .htaccess, may be one of those caused the problem. but I also changed the permission back to how those should be, according to drupaler's tips.

Comment: Today, my situation got a small progress that when I UNCHECKED "Aggregate and compress CSS files" from admin/development/performance, then the theme&css are almost back to entire site's looking. but all pictures of my site are still missing, not sure those are all from sites/default/files...?

Comment: I'm thinking you have a different location for your picture's path and there was a redirect in your .htaccess file. I would check the page for console errors to identify the path and compare that to where the images are located on the server.

Comment: If you are importing css files via css files, Drupal won't be able to aggregate those files. So @imports don't work. You could either use SASS/Less to compile your CSS or add all of your CSS files to your theme and then let Drupal aggregate the files.

Comment: Nmillin, I found a solution that opening the .htaccess at sites/default/files and change this code [Options +SymLinks] to [Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch], then all pictures came back properly,,,don't know why. but thank you very much for your great help!!!